# What do you say to mean "The subject X is taught in the n-th time slot of the day"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request

I assume that in English schools a number of subjects are taught in a day, like

- 9:00 - 10:00 English
- 10:10 - 11:10 Math
- 11:20 - 12:20 Science

What are standard phrases to express these? What I can think of are:

- We have English for the first hour.
- We learn Math for (in?) the second hour.

Are these correct? And/or are there other phrases commonly used?

Comment: If by English schools you mean schools in England note that we study maths not math which they study in the US.

Comment: @mdewey i think sundowner means english speaking schools not english as in england

Comment: @mdewey Actually I meant just English-speaking, but you mean "maths" is used in England (only? not in other parts of UK?)? How about in writing a time table, say. Do people just write Mathematics (i.e. maths is exclusively colloquial - actually my browser warns *maths* is a misspelling...)?

Comment: I think maths is universal in the UK and possibly in some other anglophone countries. People would write it in full in a timetable, title of a degree and so on but a student would say "We have double maths on Friday afternoons" or say "I am doing Maths, Further Maths and Physics at A-level" or say "I am no good at maths".

Comment: @sundowner see '[US vs. UK: Mathematical Terminology](https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2015/05/20/us-vs-uk-mathematical-terminology/)'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note: Don't forget to upvote the question too!

---

I think the word you're looking for is *period*.

Eg1:

> I have English for 1st period, Maths for 2nd period and Science for 3rd period.

Eg2

Even Stevens

[Sixth Period Even Stevens the Musical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35cf-38VDtg)

I'm not sure if 'hour' is incorrect, but I so far haven't heard at least in American English. Maybe in British English they say hour?

---

Updates based on comments:

1. No, in the UK we too use the word "period" – Peter Jennings
2. You might also use "block", if there are fewer ...periods....during the day. I'd say that might be more common in high school/college than lower schools, since there are typically fewer slots as the classes tend to be longer. – BruceWayne
3. At my high school in Michigan in the 2000s, class periods were always called "hours" instead of "periods." Maybe it varies somewhat randomly. –
   Tanner Swett
4. To me (Australian ESL), "block" would suggest a time slot which is usually/normally/etc multiple periods; eg. if there are 2 periods before recess, one might say "morning block" to refer to periods 1 and 2 collectively, perhaps on a day with a special program, or a year level which uses them for double periods, or in contexts where the lessons themselves are not directly relevant. – Jiří Baum
5. At my high school in New York, class periods were 40 minutes with 5 minutes for changes between classrooms, so we definitely would not have said "hour". – David K

Comment: No, in the UK we too use the word "period"

Comment: @PeterJennings well there you go. it's period in both US and UK.

Comment: You might also use "block", if there are fewer ...periods....during the day. I'd say that might be more common in high school/college than lower schools, since there are typically fewer slots as the classes tend to be longer.

Comment: At my high school in Michigan in the 2000s, class periods were always called "hours" instead of "periods." Maybe it varies somewhat randomly.

Comment: "Period" seems to be the best option here

Comment: @BruceWayne added

Comment: @TannerSwett added

Comment: To me (Australian ESL), "block" would suggest a time slot which is usually/normally/etc multiple periods; eg. if there are 2 periods before recess, one might say "morning block" to refer to periods 1 and 2 collectively, perhaps on a day with a special program, or a year level which uses them for double periods, or in contexts where the lessons themselves are not directly relevant.

Comment: At my high school in New York, class periods were 40 minutes with 5 minutes for changes between classrooms, so we definitely would not have said "hour".

Comment: @JiříBaum added

Comment: @DavidK added your comment to the answer